# Prove a tautology using truth table

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

How do I prove $(\lnot p \rightarrow F)\rightarrow (p=T)\;$ ***using a truth table***?

(This tautology symbolizes a "proof by contradiction". If p being false leads to a contradiction, then p is true.)

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you tried to set up a truth table. What did that look like? Where did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Well since it is only one variable I don't know how to set it up

Comment: In truth table, there are no contradictions.

Answer (score 3):

Recall: the only time an implication is FALSE is if the antecedent is true and the consequence is false.

$p\quad \mid \lnot p \quad \mid \lnot p \rightarrow F \mid p = T \mid (\lnot p \rightarrow F)\rightarrow (p = T)$
$T\quad \mid \;F\;\quad \mid \;\;T\quad \;\;\mid \quad T\quad\mid\quad \quad\quad\quad T$
$F \quad \mid \;T\;\quad\mid \;\;F \quad \;\;\mid\quad F\quad \mid\quad\quad\quad\quad T$

Hence, whatever the truth-value of $p$, the statement as a whole is true. Therefore:

$$(\lnot p \rightarrow F)\rightarrow (p = T)$$

is a tautology.

Comment: Nice, clear, easy to follow +1!

Comment: I should go back, (first refresh my memory about formatting tables) and create a proper truth-table!

Comment: Yeah, for the longest time I was using things like Scientific Word, so going back to manually cranking stuff has taken a little work! :-)

Comment: I still look things up and use examples too. I wish the the extra $ would not be needed so we can use straight LaTex. Maybe that is too difficult for the preprocessor for some reason. I have even gone back and read/reviewed/studied Latex summaries and there are some really quick people on here!

Answer (score 0):

> $(\lnot p \rightarrow F)\rightarrow (p=T)$ ... This tautology symbolizes a "proof by contradiction"

Really??? I don't know any propositional language in which this is even well-formed. Which textbook sets things up so this expression is legitimate? For a start *normal propositional languages don't have an identity relation in them*.

I suspect you are confusing this with either

> $(\neg p \to \bot) \to p$

or

> $(\neg p \to \bot) \to (p \leftrightarrow \top)$

both of which are indeed tautologies. The first of these is the one that more immediately reflects a proof by contradiction.